# JAVA_HOME env var in WSL return the error "not defined correctly' when a try run a mvn command

Tags: linux, bash, java, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I set the JAVA_HOME with the command `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` and tried to run an app with `mvn compile jib:build`.

But return this message: **The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.**

Comment: probably `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` is indeed not a valid JAVA_HOME, it's the path to the java executable itself. The proper JAVA_HOME would be it's parents' parent, i.e.:

```shell
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```